# Does the Oghma Infinium count towards Reader?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements

After completing the deadric quest "Discerning the Transmundane" you obtain a skill book called Oghma Infinium. This is a skill book and gives +5/+4 to particular skills depending on which path you choose when reading the book.

The book is only allowed to read once (unless a glitch is exploited), but I noticed when I read the book (which was only once) the total number of skills books I have read did not go up. This therefore did not count towards the "Reader" achievement. Why isn't this book considered a skill book?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only books that count towards the [reader](http://www.trueachievements.com/a157066/reader-achievement.htm) achievements are the +1 to skill books.

The Oghma Infinium, even though its technically a book, is a special case as its also a daedric artifact and thus doesn't fall under that category.